# Cannot get lineHeight from dom element style using React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom

I'm trying to get the current number of lines in a dom element using react, but i can't seem to get the curent lineHeight style from it, it always returns me empty string `""`

the first `console.log` shows me `""` and the second one `NaN` because lineHeight is a string and it should return me an integer like `20` which represents the lineHeight

Also tried not using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and nothing changed

Also noticed every single style prop is empty

What am i missing out?

`descriptionRef.current?.style?.lineHeight` also returns `""`

```
const descriptionRef = useRef<HTMLParagraphElement>();

const getNumberOfLines = () => {
  if (!descriptionRef.current) return true;

  const lineHeight: number = parseInt(
    descriptionRef.current?.style?.lineHeight ||
    document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(descriptionRef.current, null).getPropertyValue("lineHeight")
  );

  console.log(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(descriptionRef.current).getPropertyValue("lineHeight"))
  console.log(descriptionRef.current?.offsetHeight / lineHeight);

  return lineHeight > 4 ? true : false;
}

return (
  <Typography 
     ref={descriptionRef}
     className={classes.description}
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }}>
  </Typography>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Me too was facing same issue. But using `window` worked for me,

```
const lineHeight= window
  .getComputedStyle(descriptionRef.current, null)
  .getPropertyValue("line-height");
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `line-height` via `style` prop to get by script. But bear in mind, `15` and `15px` are different things for `line-height` attribute.
If we remove the style attribute, even we specify the `line-height` in CSS class, we cannot get its value as `12px` and it will be empty as same as your case.

```css
/* It doesn't matter you specify or not in CSS */
.div-class {
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

```
(
  <div ref={divRef} className="div-class" style={{ lineHeight: '15px' }}>
  </div>
)
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log({ lineHeight: divRef.current.style?.lineHeight }); // {lineHeight: '15px'}
}, []);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, I still get an empty string

Comment: What is stored in descriptionRef, and which element Typography creates?

Comment: Typography generates a `HTMLParagraphElement` and descriptionRef has a `React.MutableRefObject<HTMLParagraphElement>`